# How to know is every circle is on the same side of a line

Tags: geometry

How can I know if every circle is on the same side of a line, like this:

[image]

Comment: Find the intersections of lines vertical to the line with the circle. Plugging the values in the line equation should give you the same sign - if they are with different signs this means that the line intersects the circle.

Comment: How are the line and the circles given? Are they given by equations in Cartesian coordinates? Or by some other method? Without saying how they are given, this question is pretty much impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given line
$$a x + b y + c = 0$$
the signed distance $d_i$ between the line and point $(x_i, y_i)$ is
$$d_i = \frac{a x_i + b y_i + c}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$$
In a computer program you might wish to use form
$$d_i = A x_i + B y_i + C$$
where
$$\begin{aligned}
A &= \displaystyle \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} \\
B &= \displaystyle \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} \\
C &= \displaystyle \frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} \\
\end{aligned}$$

If the center of a circle $i$ is at $(x_i, y_i)$, and its distance $\lvert d_i \rvert$ to the line is less or equal to its radius $r_i$, i.e. $\lvert d_i \rvert \le r_i$, the circle intersects the line.

If all circles fulfill $d_i \lt -r_i$, or if all circles fulfill $d_i \gt r_i$, they are all on the same side of the line.  Otherwise, some of the circles either intersect with the line or are on different sides of the line.

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUJZY.png)

For $n$ circles,

$S =\dfrac{1}{2n}\sum [sign(x-R)+sign(x+R)]$

if $S=+1$ then all the circles are on the right side of (D)

else if $S=-1$ then all the circles are on the left side of (D).